# Easiest way in PHP to calculate percentage of weekdays passed in current month?

Tags: php, date

I am not even sure where to start with achieving this function using PHP, as I am not too familiar with the date function.  I searched a bit on the internet and did not find anything for this except for excel formulas, which obviously do not help.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: what is the excel formula?

Answer (score 2):

```
$percentage = (date('j') / date('t')) * 100;
```

Should do it.

Comment: Doesn't this take into account all days of the month and not just weekdays?  How would you do the same thing, just taking into account weekdays?

Comment: @user3765935 true, I had missed the weekdays demand to be honest!

Answer (score 0):

This is from the php manual:

> Most spreadsheet programs have a rather nice little built-in function called NETWORKDAYS to calculate the number of business days (i.e. Monday-Friday, excluding holidays) between any two given dates. I couldn't find a simple way to do that in PHP, so I threw this together. It replicates the functionality of OpenOffice's NETWORKDAYS function - you give it a start date, an end date, and an array of any holidays you want skipped, and it'll tell you the number of business days (inclusive of the start and end days!) between them.

(http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#101379)

You can try with this to get a number of weekdays in current month. After that you calculate how much weekdays are passed in current month. And based on the that results you calculate the percentage.